# Adding a view filter for taxonomy term

Tags: views

Got a bit of problem setting up my view filter for taxonomy term.

Here is what I want to do;
I want my view page to display a filter(drop down) where users can select a item and pictures will appear.

What I've done:
I have created a new content type with a picture field and a taxonomy term(item) and in that taxonomy term I have entered some random values. I added some random content from that content type with a number on taxonomy terms. Right so forward to my view.

In my fields area I have the content of the taxonomy term(item) and also my picture field.

In my filter criteria I have the content type itself AND the has taxonomy term. In that I have choose the taxonomy term (item) and added the operator of "is one of" and I can see all my listed taxonomy terms.

Ok so cool, my drop down appears and I can see all of my taxonomy terms I have listed before and i can then select a item. BUT the problem is that the content does not show on the taxonomy term. Everything shows on Any but when it comes to a taxonomy term it does not display. It's wired because I can see the taxonomy term displayed above the picture.

Any idea what I've missed.

Sorry for messy text, hope I explained it well enough.

Cheers

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand your problem. Can I see any example of what you done?

Comment: It will be clear to understand if you add some image of view page and display page instated of writing so much.